# mciSendString возвращает один символ

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

Хочу вернуть время и текущую позицию музыки, воспроизводимой с помощью mciSendString в С++

```
char* pos = new char[128];
char* dur = new char[128];

mciSendString(L"status MY_SND position", (LPWSTR)pos, 128, 0);
mciSendString(L"status MY_SND length", (LPWSTR)dur, 128, 0);

cout << pos << endl << dur << endl;
clear();
continue;
```

Но программа выводит лишь один символ размера аудио. Например, в моём случае музыка на 5 минут (300 секунд), в результате dur хранит в себе лишь один символ 3.

Comment: Интересно, что будет для `wchar_t* pos = new wchar_t[128]; .... wcout << pos;`...

Comment: @Harry всё то же. Уже пробовал

Comment: @Harry Прошу прощения, не заметил wcout. Оно выводит dur как 348838. Это очень близко к секундам размера музыки (349). Я так понимаю, это размер в милисекундах? Могу я получить длину в минутах и секундах из этого числа?

Comment: `(LPWSTR)dur` делает не то, то вы думаете, что оно делает. Передавайте указатель на настоящий буфер wchar_t

Answer (score 1):

`mciSendString` в режиме Unicode (который, судя по `L"status MY`... вы и используете) в качестве второго параметра использует массив широких символов.

то есть вам надо использовать буфер типа `wchar_t*`, создавая его статически или динамически, например,

```
wchar_t* dur = new wchar_t[128];
mciSendString(L"status MY_SND length", dur, 128, 0);
```

Что именно содержится в буфере (если, конечно, функция возвращает нулевое значчение, говорящее о том, что она завершилась успешно) - зависит от переданной команды.